# Python how to print output file into two columns?

Tags: python, excel

I don't know why my format looks so bad, so i provide a screenshot of that, thanks

[screenshot of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdUJq.png)

here is my code:

```
import xlrd                       #read excel
import urllib.request             #read url


path= 'F:/4480/ASSIGNMENT.xlsx'           #my excel path
data = xlrd.open_workbook(path)          #myexcel

table=data.sheets()[0]              #first sheet


for x in table.col_values(0):       #first column(URL column)
    print (x)
    try :
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(x)
        print(response.getheader('ETag'))
    except :
        print("not url")
```

so basically, the output is :

```
image URL
not url
http://images.ctfassets.net/55tpbg0qcsp4/1xjp4PdyFy2eUCIOkSOMWw/a923617148e873a8304477043386602d/1000x700.jpg?w=284&h=240
"42b140ed9e700be672c586933f45f792"
http://images.ctfassets.net/55tpbg0qcsp4/5zeVQCnhqowcwiIw4kM80S/f70edd51832e8640f72c375cb1d72b6b/nagative_farewell4.jpg?w=284&h=240
"4ea3a7262ceb6d451cfe6472eea82983"
```

but what I want is :

```
image URL    NOT URL
HTTP://      "XXXX"
```

AND save the output into another file(and further on, I want to use the  column value, so which file I should use? txt?)

Comment: You could try saving it as a csv file, but use tab instead of the usual comma as a delimiter.

Comment: hi,sir,can you tell me how to do that? im really new on python

Comment: I've added an answer on how to write a CSV file by just modifying your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSV file as the output and have the delimiter set as a tab.

```
import csv
import xlrd                    
import urllib.request             

csv_file = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file , delimiter='\t')

path= 'F:/4480/ASSIGNMENT.xlsx'
data = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

table = data.sheets()[0]

writer.writerow(('image URL', 'not url')) 

for x in table.col_values(0):
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(x)
        # Write normal row
        writer.writerow((x, response.getheader('ETag')))
    except:
        # Write invalid row
        writer.writerow((x, "not url"))

# Finally close the file
csv_file.close()
```

Of course you can tweak it and use a comma(`delimiter=','`) as your delimiter if you want a normal CSV file.

**Edit:** Changed sample code to use posters excel read feature